# Why do so many people on SE:Aviation have to do something with programming?

Tags: discussion, users

Just something I noticed. When I expand the user card of the people here on SE:Aviation, I do really often see people who have something to do with coding. Is that just me or are people who program generally interested into Aviation.

To support my theory, I opened a random question here on SE:Aviation: [Are seaplanes allowed to fly in residential areas?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/37866/are-seaplanes-allowed-to-fly-in-residential-areas) At the time I opened the question, there were *four* expandable usercards. *Three* of those users have something to do with code.

Or here: [Why must one wait 48 hours to fly, after scuba diving?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/13269/why-must-one-wait-48-hours-to-fly-after-scuba-diving)

Or here: [What does it take to maintain a private pilot certificate?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/758/what-does-it-take-to-maintain-a-private-pilot-certificate) On this question, nearly everyone has got an account on StackOverflow as well and speaks about coding in their "About me"-Section.

Is it just because people come here from StackOverflow, or do programmers like aviation?
(It's the same for me by the way, I also love to code)

Comment: I'm guessing most people came to the SE network for programming or computer questions. SO is the main site on the network. Then people branched out when they found other sites covering their interests.

Comment: @fooot looks like an answer

Comment: @fooot that's exactly how I ended up here. I went SO for some help programming, then whilst I was there I saw Aviation.SE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I work in a small company of around 35 people with 11 programmers. Of those 11 programmers, 3 are pilots,myself included, so way above the statistical average.

All of the pilots I've known also enjoy technology, sciences, working from facts, procedures, structured approaches, striving for excellence, self-criticism (although programmers tend to be weaker in this area) and asking "which idiot did this" so there are obvious common traits.

Answer (score 10):

Historically the stack exchange network started as a [trilogy of sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157006/what-is-the-stack-overflow-trilogy) around coding, server admin, and other compiuter-related topics.

As the network grew, I guess IT people gravitated towards the other subjects which interested them, such as aviation.

Comment: Exactly - they were probably the ones who even proposed other new SE sites including Aviation.SE : )

Answer (score 6):

I am late to answer this one, but can think of a number of reasons for this:

- Aviation and programming are both technical fields, so I would expect to see some crossover here. The same types of people tend to gravitate to both.
- Programming is generally a well-paying field, and there will be more people than average who have the means to become a pilot.
- Professional pilots generally have a fair amount of free time, both while working (sitting in hotels) and while not flying (sitting at home) in between trips. This gives them the time and resources to explore other interests, especially ones like programming which can be done from anywhere.
- They both require the mindset of "perpetual learning" since the fields are so large and complex that it's impossible for someone to know everything about it. Again, similar personality types are generally attracted to them both because of this.

Personally, I was a pilot / "free time programmer" and was active on SO before Aviation.SE was even proposed on Area 51. I was very excited to have a place with the same format as SO where aviation questions could be asked since it does involve so many technical aspects with well-defined Q&A's. I put a lot of time and energy into helping the site get up and going, and am very happy that it has turned out as well as it has.

Thank you all for making my early visions come true and making this a truly valuable resource for the aviation community as a whole!!

Answer (score 4):

I think a few of us actually work developing avionics. I find Aviation.SE a good place to expand my exposure to the industry and address aviation software specific questions.